# Image not staying inside div when window is large

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image which needs to be in a particular location, so I made a `div` in the place where I need it to be and added an `img` tag inside it, however although the `img` tag is inside the `div` tag the image goes into the bottom right corner of the page. This does not happen when the browser window is small.

**CSS:**

```
#teamimg {
    width:10%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    overflow: auto;
    float:left;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="teamimg">
<img src="Images/picture.png" alt="Image" height="18" width="20" class="itemImg" style="float:left">
</div>
```

Comment: you can use position:absolute or fixed as well

Comment: Maybe a JSFiddle? :)

Comment: The code you posted works fine, so I would imagine the problem lies in the code you didn't post. A live code snippet that demonstrates the problem (or equivalently, a jsFiddle) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Set `overflow:hidden` on the `#teamimg` rule, then you can put the image as a `background-image` with `background-size:cover;`. :)